# Copy Paste Link To Facebook Post Not Showing Thumbnail Image

Tags: php

I have a specific requirement in a project like count the user click rate on the posted link over social networking site (for now facebook.com only) and the count should store in my website database.
The actions are - 
1- I have generated the URL (redirect url to my website, when users click on the image) like this -

e.g - 
Redirect URL - http://splitmedia.in/receive?partnerLinkHash=xdZ2iOSv07rS-cN&userReferenceHash=bN19UFgRVdRS8JqkqAiu4WpCPoXEbJRYrsUowNIK-9XYfC4O-yzxY_HHoS1_2qIetWSpoQIs0hw

where partnerLinkHash & userReferenceHash is unique hash code generated for the user and link.

and the image thumbnail link which should show while posting to facebook like -

Image URL - https://bookmein.in/myAssets/images/xexp400.jpg.pagespeed.ic.6Ww3IaWPD9.jpg

Now 
When I post the redirect url to my facebook, the image url thumbnail should show and when click on this thumbnail it should redirect to the redirect url.
I tried this, but it could not work for me
example copy and paste this following link on facebook, it does not work -

```
< link rel='shortlink' href='RedirectUrl' src='Image Url'/ >
```

Comment: you have to place the image in an og-graph meta tag

Comment: give [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) a quick run through

Comment: I have tried the facebook graph api, but it did not work for me. The urls need to copy manually. Can you give me example code for this - I just copy and paste to facebook  - and it should work

Comment: place this in the head tag of the page `<meta property="og:image"
content="https://bookmein.in/myAssets/images/xexp400.jpg.pagespeed.ic.6Ww3IaWPD9.jpg" />`

Comment: Thank you,
But what about the redirect url, How can I redirect to the my website url on click of the image?

Comment: you just make another og meta property, that link I commented has all the information you need. specifically you need the `og:url` property

Comment: I tried the same but on click of image, it is showing image only not redirecting to my website.

Comment: [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) will tell you what's wrong with your URL and what facebook can see

Comment: Ok but In my case requirement is slightly different. Have a look at http://splitmedia.in link page - here publisher (user) can copy and paste the url of the specifig image and share it to facebook. And we are tracking the clicks on that post.

Answer (score 0):

You have to user og-graph meta tag and then update the facebook image cache.
To update it cache you have to go on facebook debug site and paste the url there.

Comment: Thanks you,
I have to redirect to my website on click of that image. How can I embed the redirect url with the image url?